# Show image for each ListItem item

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, webforms

So I am working on a web page in ASP.NET and I have an ImageView. What I want to do with it it's the following:

1. Foreach item in ListItem (combobox) to show an image in the ImageView I mentioned before.
2. When I select one item from the ListItem, hide the ImageView.

I am already using title as a tooltip for each items.
I have no idea how to implement the part with ImageView Image for each Item.

Comment: You have an ImageView or a ListView?Because there's no control in ASP.NET web forms called ImageView

Comment: By ImageView I meant the simple Image control from ASP.NET

Comment: Please post your code so I can see what you have so far.Post the .aspx code and the code behind